# Violinplot from histogram values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

Apologies if a question already exists that answers this; I could not find it.

I wish to make a violinplot for a dataset. For each of the elements in this set, I have the histogram values (bins & frequencies), but not the data that resulted in that histogram.

Is there a way to use either Matplotlib or Seaborn's violinplot functions in such a case? As far as I can tell, the input should be the unbinned rather than the binned data.

It would be possible to write a custom violinplot function I suppose, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker, cleaner way within existing frameworks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create sample values from the histogram data. This can be achieved via a random uniform sampling for each bin, where the number of samples is controlled via the frequencies. Then, those samples can be the input to a violin plot. If you have very few bins, a triangular distribution might give a nicer plot. If the frequencies are low, you might want to multiply them to obtain more samples.

Here is some sample code comparing the "real" and the "simulated" violinplot:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x0 = np.random.normal(np.repeat(np.random.uniform(10, 20, 10), 100), 1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 3))

sns.violinplot(x0, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('violin plot from original data')

frequencies, bin_edges = np.histogram(x0)
axes[1].bar(bin_edges[:-1], frequencies, width=np.diff(bin_edges), ec='w', lw=1, align='edge')
axes[1].set_title('histogram')

x1 = np.random.uniform(np.repeat(bin_edges[:-1], frequencies), np.repeat(bin_edges[1:], frequencies))
sns.violinplot(x1, ax=axes[2])
axes[2].set_title('violin plot from simulated data')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing plot]

Here is an experiment to show what happens when the result of the simulation is used as the input of a next simulation. Every step flattens the shape a bit. As the reshaping happens slowly, only every 20<sup>th</sup> step is visualized.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x0 = np.random.normal(np.repeat(np.random.uniform(10, 20, 7), 100), 1)
xs = []
for i in range(101):
    if i % 20 == 0:
        xs.append(np.copy(x0))
    frequencies, bin_edges = np.histogram(x0)
    x0 = np.random.uniform(np.repeat(bin_edges[:-1], frequencies), np.repeat(bin_edges[1:], frequencies))

sns.violinplot(x=np.repeat(np.arange(len(xs)) * 20, len(xs[0])), y=np.ravel(xs), color='turquoise')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing simulations]

Comment: Does this answer your question?